# Difference between cell height and inlineShape height in word

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I have a chart that I copied from excel into a word table cell. Now I am trying to resize it. Due to company rules I have to use access-vba for all of that.

This line resizes the graph alright ...

```
wdDoc.inlineShapes(1).ScaleHeight = (wdDoc.Tables(3).Cell(2,1).Height)
```

but

```
MsgBox (wdDoc.Tables(3).Cell(2,1).Height)    '= 410
MsgBox (wdDoc.inlineShapes(1).Height)        '= 942.65
```

Why is there a resize to an arbitrary number? The Width is 1393,3 pts so it is no confusion between width and height ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer:

> inlineShape.ScaleHeight: Scales the height of the specified inline shape relative to its original size.

That means that I did not scale it to 410 points of height but just to 410 percent of its former height.

The solution to my problem is to use `.height` and `.width` and calculate a ratio first.

```
Dim sizeRatio as Double

With .inlineShapes(1)

    sizeRatio = .Height / .Width
    .Height = wdDoc.Tables(3).Cell(2,1).Height
    .Width = wdDoc.Tables(3).Cell(2,1).Height / sizeRatio

End With
```